# Need a regular expression for wpf lostfocus events

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, regex, visual-studio-2010

I need to remove all lost focus events from a very large xaml file. I am planning to do this by finding and replacing (ctrl + H) all lost focus events by an empty string e.g.

replace

```
LostFocus="txtSampleLostFocus"
```

with

```
"" -> Empty String.
```

To do this I want to create a regular expression that will match my lost focus events' signature and then replace them all. Is that even possible? If yes what will be the regular expression that I will need to use?

**EDIT**

Naming pattern starts with **LostFocus="** and has text in between (a-z, 0-9) and ends with **"**

Comment: Provide naming pattern of this events.

Comment: Why do not use just FindAndReplace? At time you will figure out right regex, you will already finish your job.

Comment: @Tigran There are multiple xaml files, each very huge :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this expression: `LostFocus=:q`
:q - is a predefined class for quoted string in VS search and replace.

Answer (score 3):

Use this regex: `LostFocus="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"` or `LostFocus="[^"]+"`.